# Debounce return timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand the principle of operation. I have a code in which I have to create a delay of 2 seconds during the twist but during the delay script should not work using the debounce script but for some reason it always returns some timer and not an answer from function that the debounce script accepts

```js
function debounce(f, ms) {
  let timer = null;

  return function(...args) {
    const onComplete = () => {
      f.apply(this, args);
      timer = null;
    }

    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(onComplete, ms);
  };
}

var delay = false;

$('.window').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
  var pozition = $(document).scrollTop();
  var block2 = $(".main_step").offset().top
  var elemId = $(this).attr('id'),
    scrollDir = event.deltaY;
  var indicatorL = $(".indicator_main").data("counter");

  if (elemId == 'steps' && scrollDir < 0 && delay === false) {

    if (indicatorL != "4") {
      $("#sli-" + indicatorL).css("display", "none");

      indicatorL = indicatorL + 1;
      $("#sli-" + indicatorL).css("display", "block");
      $(".indicator_main").data("counter", indicatorL);
      $(".indicator_main").animate({
        "left": "+=25%"
      }, "slow");
      $(".indicator_num").text("0" + indicatorL);
      $(".step_nr").text("0" + indicatorL);
    }
  }

  delay = true;
  var f = function() {
    var delay = false;
    return delay;
  };

  delay = debounce(f, 2000);
  console.log(delay);
});
```

Comment: What do you expect the console to log exactly? Your denounced function is not ran anywhere as far as i can tell

Comment: Debounce is an asynchronous action, your function is not even executed at the moment you executed debounce. You can console.log inside your `f` to see when the delay variable changed